# web2py and wordpress on lighttpd

Tags: php, python, wordpress, web2py, lighttpd

I have python web2py installed on lighttpd server, 
but i want to add wordpress for blogging, 
the problem is i want wordpress to be on site.com/blog not as subdomain,
How can i manage lighttpd configuration to run!

```
url.rewrite-once = (
           "^/$" => "/ad",
            "^(/.+?/static/.+)$" => "/applications$1",
            "(^|/.*)$" => "/fcgihandler.fcgi$1", <-- tried to exclude 
            "/blog$" => "$0", <-- tried to exclude /blog from rewriting
    )
```

also added fastcgi support for php-cgi

```
fastcgi.server = (
            ".fcgi" => ("localhost" => (
                    "check-local" => "disable",
                    "min-procs" => "1",
                    "max-procs" => "2",
                    "socket" => "/tmp/web2py.sock"
            )),
            ".php" => ("localhost" => (
                    "socket" => "/tmp/php.socket"
            ))
    )
```

Couldn't do it though,
any advices please !

Comment: Have you tried putting  "/blog$" => "$0" as the first line in the rewrite rule?

Comment: Check this, could help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295096/lighttpd-rewrite-for-wordpress-inside-cakephp?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys in fact your comments helped me a lot to figure out the issue,
it worked for me as follow:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/blog(.*)$" {
            server.indexfiles = ("/")
            server.document-root = "/var/www"
    }


 url.rewrite-once = (
            "^/blog(.*)$" => "$0", <-- as @dhunter suggested 
            "^(/.+?/static/.+)$" => "/applications$1",
            "(^|/.*)$" => "/fcgihandler.fcgi$1",
    )

fastcgi.server = (
            ".fcgi" => ("localhost" => (
                    "check-local" => "disable",
                    "min-procs" => "1",
                    "max-procs" => "2",
                    "socket" => "/tmp/web2py.sock"
            )),
            ".php" => ((
                    "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi",
                    "socket" => "/tmp/php.socket"
            ))
```

hope it helps someone later !
Thanks

Comment: Glad it works, I use lighty a lot but with mod simple-vhost, adding sites is a no brainer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rewrite:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "domain.com" {

server.document-root = "/var/www/app/webroot/"
url.rewrite-once = (
       "^/blog/(.*)$" => "/blog/index.php/$1",
       "^/$" => "/ad",
        "^(/.+?/static/.+)$" => "/applications$1",
        "(^|/.*)$" => "/fcgihandler.fcgi$1",
 )

 }
```